# Show that the following two metrics are topologically equivalent.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

This is the definition of topological equivalence I'm working with.

Definition: Let $X$ be a set and $d_1$ and $d_2$ be two metrics on $X$. Then $d_1$ and $d_2$ are topologically equivalent if for every $x \in X$, for every $r > 0$, there exists $s = s(r,x)$ such that $B_s^{d_1}(x) \subset B_r^{d_2}(x)$ and $B_s^{d_2}(x) \subset B_r^{d_1}(x)$.

Note, this definition uses the same $s$. I know in other textbooks there are usually two different $s_1$ and $s_2$.

I am trying to prove that $d_1(x,y) = |x-y|$ the euclidean norm is topologically equivalent to $d_2(x,y) = |e^x - e^y|$ using the above definition.

I'm having trouble with bounding and finding a suitable $s$ since there are exponentials involved.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is equivalent to the standard definition because if the inclusions are true for $s_1$ and $s_2$ then take $s:=\min(s_1,s_2)$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the map $f:\mathbb{R}\to (0,+\infty)$ given by $f(x)=e^x$. This is a continuous bijection with continuous inverse $f^{-1}:(0,+\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f^{-1}(x) = \log(x)$.

Now fix $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $r>0$. By continuity of $f$ there is some $\delta_1 > 0$ such that for all $y\in \mathbb{R}$ the following holds:
$$
|x-y|< \delta_1 \Rightarrow |e^x - e^y| < r.
$$
Similarly, by continuity of $f^{-1}$ at $u=e^x$ there is some $\delta_2 > 0$ such that for all $v\in (0,+\infty)$ we have that
$$
|u-v| < \delta_1 \Rightarrow |\log(u)-\log(v)| < r.
$$
Write $v = e^y$ for some (unique) $y\in \mathbb{R}$, then we obtain that for all $y\in\mathbb{R}$
$$
|e^x - e^y| < \delta_1 \Rightarrow |x-y| < r.
$$
Now take $s=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$. The inclusions between the balls are just rewritings of the above implications.

Comment: Did you mean to write $u = e^x$ after the "Similarly, by continuity of $f^{-1}$......"?

Comment: @MattAdamBarnes yes! You're right. It is fixed now.